# mongo server crashes, got signal 11 (segmentation fault)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed mongoDB (3.2.13) on system with following configuration:

CPU    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz (8 core(s))
Version    Plesk Onyx v17.5.3_build1705170317.16 os_Ubuntu 16.04OS    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

It work well for a day, but after that, mongo server crashes and we get the following logs in mongoDB,

```
2017-06-08T15:09:54.173+0200 I COMMAND  [conn100] command poker.Email command: find { find: "Email", skip: 0, snapshot: true } planSummary: COLLSCAN $
2017-06-08T15:09:54.181+0200 I COMMAND  [conn101] command applogs.App_ServiceLogs command: getMore { getMore: 28832802106, collection: "App_ServiceLo$
2017-06-08T15:09:56.526+0200 I COMMAND  [conn102] command poker.App_HistoryUpdateLogs command: getMore { getMore: 72706932104, collection: "App_Histo$
2017-06-08T15:09:56.629+0200 I COMMAND  [conn103] command applogs.App_Logs command: getMore { getMore: 22128407926, collection: "App_Logs" } planSumm$
2017-06-09T08:18:01.930+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3317] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] se$
2017-06-09T08:18:03.039+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3318] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] se$
2017-06-09T08:18:03.187+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3323] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] se$
2017-06-09T08:18:03.278+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3315] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] se$
2017-06-09T12:07:56.990+0200 F -        [thread1] Invalid access at address: 0x30000009d
2017-06-09T12:07:56.999+0200 F -        ******[thread1] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).******

0x1543942 0x15428e9 0x15432c7 0x7f2a1e341390 0x1bc2a2f 0x1bb9fa1 0x1c6c6d7 0x1c6da24 0x1c6ea39 0x1c5c651 0x1bd892d 0x7f2a1e3376ba 0x7f2a1e06d82d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":
[{"b":"400000","o":"1143942","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"11428E9"},{"b":"400000","o":"11432C7"},{"b":"7F2A1$
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x1543942]
mongod(+0x11428E9) [0x15428e9]
mongod(+0x11432C7) [0x15432c7]
libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f2a1e341390]
mongod(+0x17C2A2F) [0x1bc2a2f]
mongod(+0x17B9FA1) [0x1bb9fa1]
mongod(+0x186C6D7) [0x1c6c6d7]
mongod(+0x186DA24) [0x1c6da24]
mongod(+0x186EA39) [0x1c6ea39]
mongod(+0x185C651) [0x1c5c651]
mongod(+0x17D892D) [0x1bd892d]
libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7f2a1e3376ba]
libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f2a1e06d82d]
```

Comment: Hi, this question belongs on serverfault.com where you will probably get better and more relevant answers to your question.

Comment: No problem. Please remove this question here if you are posting it on Server Fault as well.

Comment: @Henkealg No it doesn't. Questions involving systems with GUI control panels are explicitly off-topic on SF. This should just be closed.

Comment: Ok, sry for leading you wrong. I did not see any indications in your question that your MongoDB installment had a GUI. The normal install on Ubuntu server is just terminal-based.